# pyspark range between is not working properly

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi everyone I'm trying to add the previous six days data (rolling sum) and store it in a column but it's not getting populated correctly.

Here is the code, I was trying to debug

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window


#function to calculate number of seconds from number of days
days = lambda i: i * 86400

df = spark.createDataFrame([
                        (1,19, "2017-03-10"),
                        (1,20, "2017-03-11"),
                        (1,21, "2017-03-12"),
                        (1,22, "2017-03-13"),
                        (1,23, "2017-03-14"),
                        (1,24, "2017-03-15"),
                        (1,25, "2017-03-18"),
                        (1,26, "2017-03-19"),
                        (1,27, "2017-03-20"),
                        (1,28, "2017-03-21"),
                        (1,29, "2017-03-22"),
                        (1,30, "2017-03-23"),
                        (1,31, "2017-03-24"),
                        (1,32, "2017-03-25"),
                        (1,33, "2017-03-26"),
                        (1,34, "2017-03-27"),
                        (1,35, "2017-03-28"),
                        (1,36, "2017-03-29"),
                        (1,37, "2017-03-30")],
                        ["id","dollars", "timestampGMT"])
df = df.withColumn('timestampGMT', df.timestampGMT.cast('timestamp'))

#create window by casting timestamp to long (number of seconds)
df = df.withColumn("timestampGMT_in_Long",(F.col("timestampGMT").cast('long')))
df = df.withColumn("from",F.col("timestampGMT_in_Long")-days(6))
df = df.withColumn("to",F.col("timestampGMT_in_Long"))
w = (Window().orderBy(F.col("timestampGMT").cast('long')).rangeBetween(-days(6),0))
df = df.withColumn('rolling_average', F.collect_list("dollars").over(w))
df.show(50,False)
llars").over(w))
df.show(50,False)
```

Here is output of above code
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtEcR.png)

```
+---+-------+-------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+----------------------------+
|id |dollars|timestampGMT       |timestampGMT_in_Long|from      |to        |rolling_average             |
+---+-------+-------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+----------------------------+
|1  |19     |2017-03-10 00:00:00|1489104000          |1488585600|1489104000|[19]                        |
|1  |20     |2017-03-11 00:00:00|1489190400          |1488672000|1489190400|[19, 20]                    |
|1  |21     |2017-03-12 00:00:00|1489276800          |1488758400|1489276800|[19, 20, 21]                |
|1  |22     |2017-03-13 00:00:00|1489363200          |1488844800|1489363200|[19, 20, 21, 22]            |
|1  |23     |2017-03-14 00:00:00|1489449600          |1488931200|1489449600|[19, 20, 21, 22, 23]        |
|1  |24     |2017-03-15 00:00:00|1489536000          |1489017600|1489536000|[19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]    |
|1  |25     |2017-03-18 00:00:00|1489795200          |1489276800|1489795200|[21, 22, 23, 24, 25]        |
|1  |26     |2017-03-19 00:00:00|1489881600          |1489363200|1489881600|[22, 23, 24, 25, 26]        |
|1  |27     |2017-03-20 00:00:00|1489968000          |1489449600|1489968000|[23, 24, 25, 26, 27]        |
|1  |28     |2017-03-21 00:00:00|1490054400          |1489536000|1490054400|[24, 25, 26, 27, 28]        |
|1  |29     |2017-03-22 00:00:00|1490140800          |1489622400|1490140800|[25, 26, 27, 28, 29]        |
|1  |30     |2017-03-23 00:00:00|1490227200          |1489708800|1490227200|[25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]    |
|1  |31     |2017-03-24 00:00:00|1490313600          |1489795200|1490313600|[25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]|
|1  |32     |2017-03-25 00:00:00|1490400000          |1489881600|1490400000|[26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]|
|1  |33     |2017-03-26 00:00:00|1490486400          |1489968000|1490486400|[27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]|
|1  |34     |2017-03-27 00:00:00|1490572800          |1490054400|1490572800|[28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]|
|1  |35     |2017-03-28 00:00:00|1490659200          |1490140800|1490659200|[29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]|
|1  |36     |2017-03-29 00:00:00|1490745600          |1490227200|1490745600|[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]|
|1  |37     |2017-03-30 00:00:00|1490832000          |1490313600|1490832000|[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37]|
+---+-------+-------------------+--------------------+----------+----------+----------------------------+
```

expected output is

```
+----------------------------+
|rolling_average             |
+------------------------+
|[19]                    |
|[19, 20]                |
|[19, 20, 21]            |
|[19, 20, 21, 22]        |
|[19, 20, 21, 22, 23]    |
|[19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]|
|[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]|
|[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]|
|[22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]|
|[23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]|
|[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]|
|[25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]|
|[26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]|
|[27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]|
|[28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]|
|[29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]|
|[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]|
|[31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]|
|[32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37]|
+------------------------+
```

can anyone please explain to me why the rangeBetween is not working properly here?

Thank you in Advanced

Comment: You are missing some days, there are gaps in your data. `rangeBetween` is working perfectly well, it's returning the last six days (fewer than six entries if there is a gap/missing day) every time

Comment: Thanks, @lain Shelvington, i was stuck for 2 hour